# Injecting specific bean to DAO using Spring profile

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, junit4, spring-profiles, springjunit4classrunner

In my webapplication there are two datasource beans in the applicationContext one is to be used for real-env and one is to be used for execution of test. The dataSource objects is injected in one DAO class. Using Spring profile how can I configure test dataSource should be injected in the DAO while running Test (JUnit) and real-env dataSource should be injected in the DAO while code deployed to real-env ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are two ways to achieve your target:

1. One way is to use two different spring config files, one for tests (JUnit) and the other for run-time (real-env).

To be used for real env:

```
<!-- default-spring-config.xml -->
<beans>

    ...other beans goes here...

    <bean id="datasource" class="xx.yy.zz.SomeDataSourceProvider1" />

</beans>
```

To be used for tests :

```
<!-- test-spring-config.xml -->
<beans>

    ...other beans goes here...

    <bean id="datasource" class="xx.yy.zz.SomeDataSourceProvider2" />

</beans>
```

In your web.xml specify **default-spring-config.xml** as the **contextConfigLocation** to be used by spring in runtime :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/default-spring-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And finally specify **test-spring-config.xml** in **ContextConfiguration** for Test :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/test-spring-config.xml")// it will be loaded from "classpath:/test-spring-config.xml"
public class YourClassTest {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource datasource;

    @Test
    public void your_function_test() {

        //use datasource here...

    }
}
```

---

2. The second approach is to use Spring profiles as you suggest (even if i prefer the first one because it is the more appropriate for this case).

First of all add those lines to your web.xml to let Spring be aware of the default profile (real-env):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>default</param-value
</context-param>
```

Now into your Spring config file (one single config file) create two different datasources :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="...">

    ...other beans goes here...

    <beans profile="default">

        <bean id="defaultDatasource" class="xx.yy.zz.SomeDataSourceProvider1" />

    </beans>

    <beans profile="test" >

        <bean id="testDatasource" class="xx.yy.zz.SomeDataSourceProvider2" />

    </beans>

</beans>
```

Then inject DataSource into your test classes using **ActiveProfiles**:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class YourClassTest {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource datasource;

    @Test
    public void your_function_test() {

        //use datasource here...

    }
}
```

Source : https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles